# How can I make Granite stone wall using geometry nodes

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

How can I make this type of stone texture? Or something similar.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried as far? What is the context? What is the texture for?

Comment: I have tried with displacement, which works well, following a tutorial, but the random sizing of the stone isn't an option.  The texture is for a wall, it can look cartoonish, Im not going for realism. 

https://ibb.co/sR3cQfc

Comment: I would go with modelling. I would just model the bricks using randomize transform for objects and vertices, sculpting and maybe decimation for the specific look. Geometry nodes might be also useful here, but it depends on how big your wall is if it's faster that just modelling. I also think, manual solution might be faster because of how the sizes differ. It might be more difficult to achieve that with nodes.

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Im working with a geo node, I saw on another tutorial, and the same instructor with the extra objects addon, has a wall I can play around with the settings. Once the geo node is set up I can apply it on the wall. But the only problem Im having is, the face of the mesh is too clean, its only affecting the edges of the mesh:

https://ibb.co/Vx5GGkP

Is there a way I can make the face look more bumpy with these geo nodes?